# In linux terminal it says file exists

Tags: linux, file, terminal, tcsh

When I run a program and I want to send output of this program in a file.
what I tried

```
> tclsh hello.tcl > temp_out.txt
```

first time it send output to temp_out.txt file but if I run again then it says
file exists

```
> tclsh hello.tcl > temp_out.txt
> temp_out.txt : File exists
```

I want that when I run this program it should delete content of file and again add output to temp_out.txt file..

Comment: which shell you are using

Comment: echo $SHELL gives "/bin/tcsh"

Comment: Turn off the `noclobber` variable.

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: See https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-tcsh/index.html

Comment: from next time I will keep this in mind.. thanks @Barmar

Comment: And since @Barmar referenced the IBM DeveloperWorks site, you may as well keep the site handy, it is a relative treasure trove for nearly all things Linux (from bash, to tsch to php to C to Ajax to SQL to...) Most of the Articles also provide a convenient .pdf as well for off-line reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running like this,

```
tclsh hello.tcl >! temp_out.txt
```

It will overwrite existing[temp_out.txt] file.

Comment: "Missing name for redirect"      getting this error

Comment: It should be `>!` not `>|`.

Comment: This is `bash` syntax, the comment above says he's using `tcsh`.